# Example where $R = F[A]$ is an integral domain.

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A\in M_n(F)$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over the field $F$ such that $A$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity. Let $R = F[A]$.

1. Find examples where $R$ is an integral domain, and one where $R$ is not an integral domain
2. Give a necessary and sufficient condition for $R$ to be an integral domain.

---

If $F$ is algebraically closed, then the minimum polynomial for all matrices will split into linear factors. Thus I don't see how we can have $R$ as an integral domain. Unless $F$ is not algebraically closed. But the question is asking about conditions on $A$ not $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*. Let $m_A$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. An equation of the form $f(A)g(A)=0$ entails $m_A \mid fg$. If $m_A$ is irreducible, then...? If not, then...?

The point is that $F[A]\simeq F[X]/(m_A(X))$, so we need $(m_A)$ to be prime in the PID $F[X]$.